Novel about human spy on another planet becomes rock musician
Looking for a novel about a human spy who infiltrated another planet for reasons unknown until the end. Though very similar to Earth, this planet doesn’t have much musical ambition or talent.
The spy takes advantage and becomes a big star playing rock music he remembers from Earth. He learns to love his new world but at the end you learn he is an advance recon agent scouting the planet for eventual conquest by Earth because Earth is dying from the damage caused by humans. He ends up killing his Earth contacts and goes full native.

Hi, welcome to SF&F. Where and when did you read this?  Was it a hardcover, paperback, or e-book?  Do you recall the cover art?

Is this Enormity (2013) by Nick Milligan...?

Before joining NASA’s space programme, Jack had dreams of a career as a professional musician. When a deep space mission goes awry, he crashes on an alien planet. Jack discovers that his new world is inhabited by a race of humans that have evolved in parallel to those on Earth. He picks up a guitar and performs the most wondrous rock songs of his home planet. Neil Young. Leonard Cohen. Bob Dylan. Superstardom beckons as audiences around the globe revere Jack and his apparent songwriting abilities. He basks in the boundless glow of a hedonistic dream world. But Jack soon learns that his lie will have sinister consequences.


